# java cannot upcast to an interface

Tags: java, interface, casting, upcasting

```
private class EntryItr implements Iterator<Map.Entry<K, V>> {
... 
}

private class KeyItr<K> implements Iterator<K> {

    private Iterator<Map.Entry<K,V>> itr;

    KeyItr(){
        itr=new EntryItr(); // CANNOT CREATE
    }
```

Why cannot upcast **EntryItr** to the previously implemented interface?

Comment: Remove the `<K>` from `KeyItr`, it hides the `k` of the enclosing class.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code you posted does not even compile. 
The generics you used are not proper: the `EntryItr` class should be declared as `EntryItr<K, V>`. Also, `KeyItr`'s `itr` field has an unrecognized generic value of type `V`. You should either change it to `Object`, or add it to `KeyItr`'s generic signature, i.e. KeyItr

After these changes, the assignment `itr = new EntryItr<>();` should be possible.

Please note the diamond operator here to denote that `EntryItr` will have same generics signature as `KeyItr`'s `itr`.